# Greenplum error "Canceling query because of high VMEM usage."

Tags: greenplum

We have a small Greenplum cluster in which some queries abort.

**System related information:**

```
Greenplum Version: 6.3
Master Host: 1
Segment Host: 2
RAM per Segmenthost: 32GB
SWAP per Segmenthost: 32GB
TOTAL segment: 8 Primary + 0 mirror
segment per host: 4

vm_overcommmit_ratio: 95
gp_vmem_protect_limit: 8072MB
statement_mem: 250MB
```

The queries are executed with a none superuser.

**Symptom:**

The query failed with the following error massage:

```
Canceling query because of high VMEM usage. Used: 7245MB, available 801MB, red zone: 7264MB (runaway_cleaner.c:189)
```

**What we tried:**

1. We calculate the Greenplum Parameter with this information: https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/6-3/best_practices/sysconfig.html

   This help us for some "simple" queries but for more complicated ones the error happend again.
2. In the next Step we configured the max_statement_mem: 2000MB

   This didn't have any effect to the memory consumption on the segmenthosts. We track this with following Query:

```
select segid, sum (vmem_mb) from session_state.session_level_memory_consumption
where query like '%<some snippet of the query>%'
group by segid
order by segid;
```

The memory consumption increases very quickly and the error happend again.

3. We tried to restrict the memory consumption by setting the following resource queue for the user:

```
CREATE RESOURCE QUEUE adhoc with (ACTIVE_STATEMENTS=6, MEMORY_LIMIT=6291);
ALTER ROLE user1 RESOURCE QUEUE adhoc;
```

The Database is set to use the resource queue with the parameter gp_resource_manager: queue

We see in the Table 'gp_toolkit.gp_resqueue_status' when we execute a statement that the 'rsqmemoryvalue' is 1048 but the memory consumption in the session_state.session_level_memory_consumption table shows higher values for the segments until the error occurs again.

Has anyone a tip to fix this problem?

Comment: Why not use Resource Groups, have you enabled them?

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will try it out and give you feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Each query will ask for 250MB memory and you set gp_vmem_protect_limit to 8GB. In this case, you can probably run (8GB- primary process memory)/250MB =~ 20-30 queries at the same time. The size of primary process depends on other settings, shared_buffers, wal_buffers,...

Statement_mem can be set in a session. This means some users can set statement_mem higher (up to max_statement_mem) and you will see less queries in concurrent.
When the memory allocated to those concurrent queries reach 90(OR 95) % of gp_vmem_protect_limit, runaway detector will start to cancel queries to protect primary process from OS OOM Kill.

To "fix" the problem (it is not a problem actually), you can

1) set lower default statement_mem, so you can have more queries running concurrently but slower.

2) increase RAM on segment hosts, such that you can increase gp_vmem_protect_limit.

Comment: Or lower the number of primary segments per host. 8 segments with only 32GB of RAM is a problem.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and the explanation of the different parameters.
Unfortunately, I do not fully understand this.
The problem occurs when only a single query is executed on the greenplum. There are no other queries that use resources and the statement_mem parameter is not overwritten in the database session. The default statement_mem parameter is ignored and the executed statement takes up more than 7GB of RAM in each segment and fails.

If I overwrite the statement_mem in the session by executing 'set statement_mem' it has no effect as well.

Comment: If you have only 1 query, gpdb will give you whatever available in default resource queue. from you context, you have over commit memory. You have 32G physical memory, but your overcommit ratio gives you about 64G address space.   when you query comes in gpdb, the default statement_mem takes affect, but may require more memory when the query needs it. Gpdb thinks I have 64G ram for query but it hits the bump when 32G ram are used.

Comment: Hi there, Did you solve this?